# KeyRemap4Macbook Vim-emulation alternative for Linux

Tags: linux, vim, keyboard, keyboard-layout, key-binding

There is a really nifty tool for Mac OS X called KeyRemap4Macbook which allows you, among other things, to use Vim keybindings to edit text in all text fields, with a distinction between normal and insert mode.

Is there a corresponding program that will do this for Linux? I've found a few that will let me launch Vim to edit the text of a text field, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. For example, on the Mac I can use a rich-text editor such as TextEdit to make the word 'bold' bold and then use the 'Vim' normal mode to replace the letter 'o' with 'a', using ra, and the text maintains its bold formatting. Editing the text in an actual Vim instance wouldn't do this.